# Prove that the language generated by the grammar $S \to SxS \mid a$ is inherently ambiguous

Tags: formal-languages, automata, ambiguity

With the following grammar:

$$S \to SxS \mid a$$

Is L(G) inherently ambiguous? What is the proof?

---

I know how to prove the grammar is ambiguous but I don't know how to prove if the grammar is inherently ambiguous. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245215/bnf-grammar-ambiguity

Comment: @LMD, the question is about the language $L(G)$, not about the grammar $G$.

Comment: @Steven "A language that only admits ambiguous grammars is called an inherently ambiguous language, and there are inherently ambiguous context-free languages." - if the grammar is not ambiguous, the language can not be inherently ambiguous (other way around doesn't work however, it would be left to prove that only ambiguous alternatives to the grammar exist).

Comment: @LMD But that grammar IS ambiguous. Therefore this says nothing on whether $L(G)$ is inherently ambiguous or not. $SxSxS$ can be generated from $SxS$ by applying the production $S \to SxS$ to either the first occurrence of the non-terminal $S$ or to the second one. These two choices produce different parse-trees.

Answer (score 2):

$L(G)$ is regular and hence not inherently ambiguous.
In particular $L(G)$ is the language described by the regular expression $a(xa)^*$.